# Hive find top n pages by plays

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, nosql

We have a table in which we want to store data for the top 100 pages.

So if the destination table top100Pages has

```
 uid string, 
 mid string, 
 pageurl string,
 plays string,
 device string
```

To fill this table, I can run:

```
SELECT uid, mid,pageurl,sum(plays),device from $sourceTable where day= $date GROUP BY uid, mid,page url,device;
```

This query will pull data for all pages. How can I modify this query so that it returns data only for the top n pages?

Answer (score 0):

The `LIMIT` clause described at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-LIMITClause limits the results, but they are chosen at random.

As you can see at that link, you could limit the reducers to 1 and then apply a specific `SORT BY` clause before the `LIMIT` to get the equivalent of a "Top N".

Comment: It looks like it will be solved using hive windowing and analytics functions. not sure how yet

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select uid, mid, pageurl, sum(plays), device
from $sourceTable
where day = $date
group by uid, mid, page url, device
order by sum(plays)
limit 100;
```